# I want to detect when a JUnit class finishes running its test methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, aop, aspectj

I want to detect when a JUnit class finishes running its test methods.

How can I detect when a Junit class finishes its unit test methods ?

And how can I similary understand that a test suite made of Junit test classes finishes its call ?

Comment: seems smelly and hacky. what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to write a AspectJ class that traces the methods of a unit tests and reports them. I can trace the methods but I need to understand when the testing finishes. It will be nice not to add source code to existing test codes but it is okey if there is no alternative solution.

Comment: junit provides listener api for exactly that purpose. so try to provide additional listener to your test runner (not to all tests). it should be possible in any build tool. not sure about IDEs though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a class finishes its unit tests, the method with annotation @AfterClass is executed. You may use that to know that your unit test methods have finished executing.

Comment: http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/ClassRule.html What about this. İs it possible to do this without adding a source code to the Junit test cases ? And what about the TestSuit ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible since Junit 4.8. An example can be found here https://dzone.com/articles/junit-49-class-and-suite-level-rules